# Extend the domain of a real analytic function

Tags: real-analysis, analyticity

Let $f:(a,b)\to \mathbb{R}$ be a real analytic function on $(a,b)$. Is there a real analytic function $g:(c,d)\to\mathbb{R}$, with $(c,d)\supset (a,b)$, such that:

$
g(x)=f(x), \ \forall\ x\in (a,b)?
$

Comment: Maybe. That depends on $f$. If $f$ has poles at $a$ and $b$ for example, it has no real-analytic (not even continuous) extensions to a strictly larger interval.

Answer (score 1):

Not always. Consider for example
$$
f(x)=\frac{1}{x(1-x)},\quad x\in(0,1).
$$